# The 'model' property does not exist in the 'IUserDocument' type

Tags: typescript, mongoose

I'm trying to create my own interface and extend the `Document` from `Mongoose`, so I did:

**users.types.ts**

```
import { Document, Model } from 'mongoose'

export interface IUser {
    chatId: Number,
    username: String,
    name?: String,
    firstName?: String,
    lastName?: String,
    age?: Number,
    sex?: String,
    partner?: String,
    updatedAt?: Date
}

export interface IUserDocument extends IUser, Document {
    setLastUpdated: (this: IUserDocument) => Promise<void>
}

export interface IUserModel extends Model<IUserDocument> {
    findOneOrCreate: ({
        chatId,
        username,
    }: {
        chatId: Number
        username: String
        age: number
    }) => Promise<IUserDocument>
}
```

and then:

**users.methods.ts**

```
import { Document } from "mongoose"
import { IUserDocument } from "./users.types"

export async function setLastUpdated(this: IUserDocument): Promise<void> {
    const now = new Date()
    if (!this.updatedAt || this.updatedAt < now) {
        this.updatedAt = now
        await this.save()
    }
}

export async function setUsername(this: IUserDocument): Promise<Document[]> {
    return this.model("user").find({ username: this.username })
}
```

Now I get the following error:

> The 'model' property does not exist in the 'IUserDocument' type. Did you mean '$model'?

on the following line:

```
return this.model("user").find({ username: this.username })
```

Also, I'm facing problem with `this` too, infact if I try to call the model in this way:

**users.statics.ts**

```
import { IUserDocument } from './users.types'

export async function findOneOrCreate({
    chatId,
    username
}: {
    chatId: Number
    username: String
}) {

    const record = await this.findOne({ chatId, username })

    if (record) {
        return record
    } else {
        return this.create(chatId, username)
    }
}
```

I get this error:

> 'this' implicitly contains the type 'any' because it does not include a type annotation.

Could someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with mongoose, but according to the documentation:

[`model()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#mongoose_Mongoose-model) is called on the moongose instance. Probably something like this

```
import mongoose, { Document } from "mongoose"
[...]
return mongoose.model("user").find({ username: this.username })
```

[`findOne()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne) and [`create()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.create) is called on the model. So you probably should input an `IUserModel` into `findOneOrCreate`.

[`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) has a special meaning in Javascript and is probably not what you want to use.